# Help to check a string pattern

Tags: apex

I have a pattern like this -: MW290290-12

I need to check the pattern of this using apex. How to do that?

Here MW will remain constant.

12 is the year , it may be 13,14 like this.

And number 290290 can be any number , can be of any digits.

Kindly help.

Comment: Try the patterns and matchers. that should definately help you out.. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm

Answer (score 2):

Run the below code in the developer console and test out all the possibilities by changing the `userinput` string:

```
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile('MW[0-9]+\\-{1}[0-9]{2}');
string userInput = 'MW290290-12';
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(userInput);
system.debug('Is there a match??  '+ myMatcher.matches());
```